# What is the data structure for a producer/transformer/consumer queue?

Tags: multithreading, data-structures, concurrency, pipeline

I have a real-time concurrent data processing pipeline, and want to enforce some memory guarantees to avoid crippling the system. Speed, memory usage, and reliability are all critical.

The pipeline follows a producer/transformer/consumer model, and my current implementation in Python uses a process for each of the agents and pipe to pass data between them. This is causing a fairly large bottleneck as the data must be serialized before going in the pipe and deserialized at the other end. I've re-written it using a shared memory approach and that helps with speed but it doesn't guarantee memory safety.

I've started redesigning the system based on a fixed, shared buffer where each thread only has access to one (or two) items at a time. This is very similar to a [bounded buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem), except that there is an additional read/write thread (transformer) between the head (producer) and tail (consumer). It looks something like this:

[image: double bounded buffer with extra]

- A (the producer) writes data (the dot) at its current position, then moves to the right.
- B (the transformer) reads two of the data at a time, writing a meta value in the rightmost position, then moves one cell to the right (releasing left cell first).
- C (the consumer) reads both data and meta at the current position and destroys both when it is done, then moves to the right.

Some additional context:

- the data items are a known fixed size, around 1 MB each
- will need to support storing a maximum of ~5000 items between A and C
- the metadata is an integer, likely stored in a separate but synchronized buffer
- A is likely to be the fastest but this is not guaranteed
- the buffer wraps around (i.e. it is backed by a ring buffer), and A shall not succeed C
- there is only one of A, B, and C; i.e. single-producer, single-consumer

This isn't a data structure I'm very familiar with, and I can't seem to find the right words to search for libraries or even some examples of how this is implemented.

**What is this data structure called, and are there any libraries/examples I can leverage?**

***Note:** I don't have a requirement to use Python, and have been experimenting with Rust and C++.*

Comment: Could the logic be simplified using two buffers? In the first buffer thread A writes its data and thread B reads and transforms its data. Thread B writes its output to the second buffer and thread C reads from the second buffer. Now you have two circular buffers, each with a single producer and a single consumer.

Comment: Sure, that would make things much more simple. I have tried something similar using GStreamer but ran into some other issues relating to bad bindings. The main problem then is that the data has to be copied over to the second buffer, which I'd like to avoid for performance reasons. It's worth noting that B and C do not modify the data, only read it and write metadata. This does give me an idea, however... I could create two queues backed by the same circular buffer; so thread B would be both a consumer and a producer. Is this safe?

Comment: Yes, that is safe as long as all producers and consumers employ appropriate synchronization controls.